# Proper way to implement persistent login for javascript based mobile app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, jwt

I'm currently working on a mobile app that is built primarily with HTML and css, then run with phonegap. Part of the app requires that the user logs in and sync data with a backend. I want it done in such a way that once the user is logged in on their device they will remain logged in until they manually log out; they should only have to enter their information once. I've found some decent information when working with native code, but not so much that applies to my situation.

Right now, I'm not sure how to properly do this in a way that is secure. My first idea was to handle the login normally, then pass back a secret code that is stored both in local storage on the device, as well as in the database under the user that was authenticated with it. On subsequent requests it would pass this and allow access to the user that had a matching secret code. My question is whether this is secure enough to be practical?

I've also done a bit of research and it appears JWT is similar to what I'm looking for? My two concerns for this approach are:

1. How do I maintain the persistent login with this method.
2. What prevents someone from spoofing a connection? From what I know there's a secret string that is passed with each request to verify it. But, since the code in my app would be visible to someone who knew how to access it what is to prevent them from learning what the secret is and spoofing a connection?

I assume my questions with JWT are due to me misunderstanding some fundamentals of how it works. If it satisfies what I'm looking to do I'd much rather use a more standardized process like JWT as opposed to writing my own solution.

Am I on the right track with what I'm thinking above or am I way off base?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct and this is how it's usually done. It is a combination of cookie and session concepts. A 'session' is started on the server once the user logs in. The session is identified by a string (e.g. md5 format) and passed back to the client. The string is saved in a cookie on the client, and since cookie info is sent in each HTTP request, the server can assign that request to the session, thus considering your user as logged in. The signout process later basically consists of removing your cookie, and / or sending a request to the server to remove the session object.
In most HTTP server side frameworks there is an API used for sessions, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. And yes, it is secure enough, as you don't usually base your security on this layer of transport, but rather on a lower layer by introducing https.